# Output not shown correctly

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C programming and I have written the following code but it is producing an error at the output. The code is-:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
  int n=0;
  int i,k;
  char name;
  printf("\t\t Program to find the overtime of 10 workers\n\n");
  for(i=0;i<=10;i++){
    printf("Enter the name of worker");
    scanf("%char",&name);
    printf("Enter the number of hours worked");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(n>10){
      k=n-10;
      printf("He is eligible for overtime for overtime of rs %d\n",k*12); 
    }
    else{
      k=0;
      printf("He is not eligible to any overtime in rs %d \n",k);
    }
  }
  getchar();
}
```

It is showing correct result for the first time but when I entered the name of the worker second time it is giving me the wrong output.I am unable to detect the mistake.

Comment: `scanf("%char",&name);` ?

Comment: You are trying to input a name into a single character, as well as having a mistake in how you are doing that. I think it is time to review how `scanf` works.

Comment: There's no such thing as `%char`. Check http://personal.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/R.Bowden/C/scanf.html.

Comment: Please don't change the question radically once there are posted answers. Now some of the answers don't make sense. You could have prevented this by posting an actual copy/paste of the real code from the start. If you have a different question, then please post a new question instead of changing the current one. I'll rollback edits.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to format specifier `%char`. It is not a valid format specifier, there is no such thing as `%char` that C understands.

Make a habit of standard library reading man pages of the functions that you are planning to use. For example, [`scanf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf). Read through **Conversions** section of that man page. That will guide you about what format specifiers are to be used with `scanf()`.

Look at the variable there:

```
char name;
```

Its a `char`, it can only hold one character.
To store a *name*, I assume that you need more than one `char`. So you might want to use an array of characters.

So, change it to:

```
char name[MAX_LENGTH_NAME];  //MAX_LENGTH_NAME can be a macro set to some value, example 32?
```

And change your `scanf()` call for worker name to,

```
scanf("%s", name);   // Note: `&` is gone here!
```

Getting the return values from `scanf()`, and adding some error handling for unexpected return will save you a lot of pain going ahead.

The `printf()` says, its a program to calculate something for 10 workers,

```
for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
```

This loops for 11 iterations, not 10. I hope you aren't the 11th worker :-).
Change it to `for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)`.

Additionally, `conio.h` is non-standard. If you are developing on a platform that mandates you using this header, you may want consider switching to a better development environment. For example, a linux machine with a bash terminal and a standard gcc compiler.

Lastly, `void main` is bad, use `int main(void)` instead. To know more on why, read [What should main() return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Irrelevant: GUI Design and what messages you throw up on console are very crucial going ahead. ***`He`*** is strictly masculine :D Aren't there any women workers around? It could be way better if you start printing the name instead of ***`He`***.

Comment: It is still giving a wrong output . I have changed %char to %c

Comment: Don'y complain before I update my answer, it had only been answered a couple of minutes ago. I can point to multiple issues in your code, and its fairly valid to more than your expected time to answer your question *entirely*.

Comment: I'm sorry to do so .It's just because I can't understand the error and want to get answer as fast as possible .I am trying to solve it for the past few days.

Answer (score 0):

1. name should be char array ==> `char name[15];`
2. The second visible error is the `for` loop: When you are looking for 10 worker entries, your array loop is running from i=0 to i=10 which would be 11 entries.
   So,   `for(i=0;i<10;i++)`  ==> `i<10` instead of `i<=10`.
3. your `scanf` statement  ==> `scanf("%s",name);`  not a `%char` which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems in your code. Firstly this

```
scanf("%char",&name);
```

is wrong, instead of `%char` you should provide the correct **format specifier** to scan the `name`. This

```
char name;
scanf("%c",&name);
```

runs successfully but I hope you don't want a person `name` in single character, so better declare `name` as array of char. For e.g

```
char name[MAX_LEN];/*define MAX_LEN] */
```

and then use

```
scanf("%s",name);
```

And the `for` loop condition `i<=10` rotates the loop `11` times not `10` times(as you mentioned 10 worker), probably you want `i<10`.

Also instead of `void main() { }` use

```
int main(void) {

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit :-** Since you modify the question. And
*It is showing correct result for the first time but when I entered the name of the worker second time it is giving me the wrong output.I am unable to detect the mistake. ?*

To avoid this

```
scanf("%c",&c);
```

should be

```
scanf(" %c",&c); /* give the white space before %c */
```

**Side note**, it's highly recommended to check the **return value** of predefined function like `scanf()` to know whether they got succeed or failed , for that read the manual page. For e.g

```
char name;
int ret = scanf(" %c",&name);
if(ret == 1) {
    /* do something */
}
else {
   /* error handling */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several problems:

- `conio.h` header is useless,
- You do not reserve enough space to store a name,
- you do not check for scanf result.

Corrected, your code could looks like:

```
/* only include stdio.h, conio.h is not portable and unnecessary here */
#include <stdio.h>

/* main should return an int*/
int main(void)
{
    int n=0;
    int i,k;
    /* often, a name is composed of several characters */
    char name[128];
    printf("\t\t Program to find the overtime of 10 workers\n\n");
    for( i=0; i<10; i++){
        printf("Enter the name of worker\n");

        if (1 != scanf("%s", name))
        {
            /* on error, exit loop */
            perror("scanf");
            break;
        }

        printf("Enter the number of hours worked\n");
        if (1 != scanf("%d",&n))
        {
            /* scanf did not manage to read one integer, exit loop */
            perror("scanf");
            break;
        }
        if (n>10) {
            k=n-10;
            printf("%s is eligible for overtime for overtime of rs %d\n", name, k*12); 

        }
        else{
            printf("%s is not eligible to any overtime in rs 0 \n",name);
        }
    }
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

---

And to finish, here: a good reading about `scanf`: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html